# Performance of editing/sculpting

Tags: performance

I have some performance concerns regarding moving vertexes in either edit or sculpt mode.

blender seems to handle editing better than sculpting. At around 20k triangles sculpting begins to slow down. I am able to get upto 300k before edit begins to slow down.

I am using viewport shading and my system supports cuda (cpu and gpu).

I have checked task manager and my system never really peaks (gpu is at 10%) (cpu gets upto 50%)

My drivers are up to date (according to windows)

Im new to blender and I don't know if im asking too much out of my computer

My specs are;

```
intel i7-3820 3.6ghz

12gb ram

nvidia geforce gtx 680
```

EDIT: ram used by blender is about 800mb's or so. my system is using about 50% total.

Comment: 50% is a lot, as the cpu may not (definitely not) be able to be used at 100%. Also have a look at ram usage

Comment: @WhatAMesh blender is barely using any ram. about 800mb, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something I've seen is that the taskbar is known to be inaccurate for showing the GPU usage. You could download something like MSI Afterburner which will allow you to see your GPU usage as it is more accurate. In the past, I've had my task manager saying I'm using 14% when I was using 100% so your problem could be that your GPU is running at 100% but task manager isn't showing it.

Link for MSI Afterburner - https://www.msi.com/Landing/afterburner